# Is there a function for adjusting the size of my ggplot chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, tidyverse

I am trying to increase the size of my `ggplot` chart:

And I tried this:

```
ggplot(accident_day, aes(year, accidents, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "THE RATE OF ACCIDENTS", x = "Year", y = "Number of Accidents")+
  theme(figure.width = 8, figure.height = 4)
```

and also this :

```
theme(plot.width = 10, plot.height = 5)
```

But got this output:

```
Error in `mapply()`:
! The `plot.width` theme element is not defined in the element hierarchy.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: If you want the plot to be larger, make your plotting window larger. The plot will grow to fit. If you want to save the plot at a particular size, use `ggsave`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the output of the plot in the HTML markdown file, you can use the following argument in the code chunk's header:

````
```{r fig.height=10, fig.width=10}
ggplot(accident_day, aes(year, accidents, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "THE RATE OF ACCIDENTS", x = "Year", y = "Number of Accidents")
```
````

You can also set the default size of the plots in the knitr setup chunk like so:

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  fig.width=10,
  fig.height=10)
```
````